# How to open .ipyjn files with preview notebook editor by default

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the latest updated version of VScode Insiders. While working with .ipyjn files I have noticed that it is WAY better to edit them with preview notebook editor instead of the classical notebook editor.

Is there a way to open these files by default with the preview editor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use VSCode insider and want the VSCode open Jupyter notebook in default editor add this line **"jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"],** to your settings.json file, otherwise remove it.

here is a [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter)